# Trying to convert an int from a textfield to an array swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift4

I am developing an iOS app, I am trying to use a textfield and a button to submit an integer into an array so that I can store it using 'userdefaults'. So far I have got a different textfield adding the String entered into the array and storing it in the user defaults.

```
     @IBAction func workBtn(_ sender: Any)
{
    let kidnum: Int = Int(enteredScore.text!)!
    kidName.append(enteredName.text!)
    kidScore.append(kidnum)

    enteredName.text?.removeAll()
    enteredScore.text?.removeAll()
}


@IBAction func finishBtn(_ sender: Any)
{
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(kidName, forKey: "Pupil Name")
    userDefaults.set(kidScore, forKey: "Pupil Score")

    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

workBtn is the add button I am using, I did also try to use a string as I don't actually need the integer for working out but just to display a score but I could not get it to save, I am passing it through it to be displayed on a table view controller cell. Thanks

I am using Xcode 9.1 Swift 4, Thanks.

Edit***
After running it I got an error in this function on the line marked stating "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var nameArray: [String] = userDefaults.object(forKey:"Pupil Name") as! [String]
    //Error occurring on next line.
    var scoreArray: [Int] = userDefaults.object(forKey: "Pupil Score") as! [Int]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(nameArray[indexPath.item]) -Score: \(scoreArray[indexPath.item])"

    userDefaults.synchronize()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please show your enteredName  and enteredScore  declaration code ?

Comment: enteredName and enteredScore are both separate UItextfields, for the Name and score of the user. kidName and kidScore are the arrays I am using to store the contents of these, the textfields then clear to allow the user to enter in more.

Comment: I can't see anything really wrong with your code; there is no need to call `synchronize` and all that force unwrapping to assign `kidnum` is just begging for a crash, but it should add to the arrays and save the arrays. What exactly is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: What exactly the problem you're facing here?

Comment: For some reason kidScore will not save or store anything and registers as empty constantly.

Comment: It seems more likely that the issue is in retrieving the data than in storing it.  Show the code where you try and use the score data

Comment: That was just one of the many ways I have tried to convert the textfield to Int Type to save/store it, could you recommend a more efficient way?

Comment: The correct way is to use conditionals `if let kidscore = Int(enteredScore.text ?? "") {…`

Comment: I thought that however when running the application through the simulator it is displaying the kidName as having the variables stored and kidScore as being empty, it then crashing when trying to display/read kidScore as there is nothing to read

Comment: If you get a crash then edit your question to indicate the crash message and the line of code where it crashed

Comment: @BigNeil Please show your full code with declaration and error ?

Comment: You shouldn't retrieve your data in `cellForRowAt` and don't use a force unwrap or you will get a crash. Also, user defaults is not really a good way to simply pass data between view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving means you are accessing a nil value somewhere where you don't expect it. This is most likely by force-unwrapping some value which you do constantly in your code. Try avoiding the usage of `!`. In your code it might be any of lines such as `let kidnum: Int = Int(enteredScore.text!)!` but it might also be some field is missing connection for instance and is declared as `@IBOutlet weak var enteredName: UITextField!` which unfortunately is a default.

To debug this you might want to enable exception breakpoint: In navigator on your left side of Xcode on the top there is an icon for breakpoints (a bullet). Select it and then check on the bottom left and find a "+" button, press it and select "Exception breakpoint...". Then simply click away. Now your execution will stop whenever an exception like yours is hit. Run your project and find the line, object that is nil and should not be. Then fix your issue.

But in general try writing your code more like the following:

```
    @IBOutlet private weak var scoreTextField: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet private weak var nameTextField: UITextField?

    private typealias NameScore = (name: String, score: Int)
    private var dataArray: [NameScore] = [NameScore]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
    }

    @IBAction private func workPressed() {
        let scoreValue: Int? = {
            guard let string = scoreTextField?.text, let integer = Int(string) else {
                return nil
            }
            return integer
        }()

        guard let score = scoreValue else {
            print("Could not parse integer value") // TODO: Show alert view
            return
        }

        guard let name = nameTextField?.text else {
            print("Name was not provided") // TODO: Show alert view
            return
        }

        dataArray.append((name: name, score: score))

        // Clear text fields
        scoreTextField?.text = nil
        nameTextField?.text = nil
    }


    @IBAction private func finishPressed() {
        saveData()
    }

    private let pupilNameKey: String = "name"
    private let pupilScoreKey: String = "score"
    private let pupilDataKey: String = "pupil_data"

    private func saveData() {
        // Let's convert data into something that makes more sense for safety
        let dataToSave: [[String: Any]] = dataArray.map { object in
            return [pupilNameKey: object.name,
                    pupilScoreKey: object.score]
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(dataToSave, forKey: pupilDataKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    private func loadData() {
        guard let savedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: pupilDataKey) as? [[String: Any]] else {
            // No saved data or incorrect format
            return
        }

        dataArray = savedData.flatMap { descriptor in
            guard let name = descriptor[pupilNameKey] as? String, let score = descriptor[pupilScoreKey] as? Int else {
                return nil // Could not parse this object
            }
            return (name: name, score: score)
        }
    }
```

And table view:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let dataObject = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(dataObject.name) -Score: \(dataObject.score)"
        return cell
    }
```

I hope the code speaks for itself on how to avoid force unwrapping and also how to pack your data.

Comment: Thank you changing a few things in the code seemed to fix it, I appreciate the help you have given me. I am new to swift so this has given me a general idea for the coding standard